# laravel question: duplicate message display when I click the button

Tags: php, laravel

I want to return the message when I click the add button. Yes, indeed it show the message. But, in my case is have 3 image shown on the same page, so the problem is show the 'add to cart successfully' for the 3 image when I click the button.

Below is the controller file, but i think is done for here.

```
public function addItem($id){
  $pro = products::find($id);
  Cart::add(['id' => $pro->id, 'name' => $pro->pro_name,
  'qty' => 1, 'price' => $pro->pro_price,
'options' =>[
  'img' => $pro->pro_img
  ]]);
    return back()->with('status', 'add to cart successfully');
}
```

Should be need to make changes on the view file, below is the view file:

```
@foreach($data as $p)

              <article class="product-grid-item product-block">
                  <figure class="product-item-thumbnail">
                      <a href="{{url('/productsDetails')}}/{{$p->pro_name}}">
                          <img
                                  src="{{asset('/img/')}}/{{$p->pro_img}}" alt=""
                                  width="400px" height="360px" />
                          <div class="product-item-mask">
                              <div class="product-item-actions">
                                  <button class="button button-secondary button-short">
                                      Quick View
                                  </button>

                                  <a href="{{url('/cart/add')}}/{{$p->id}}" class="button add-cart-cat button--small card-figcaption-button">Add to Cart</a>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </a>
                  </figure>


                  <div class="product-item-details">
                      {{--Add Cart Message--}}
                      @if (session('status'))
                          <div class="alert alert-success">
                              {{ session('status') }}
                          </div>
                      @endif
                      {{--End of Add Cart Message--}}
                      <div class="product-item-brand"><label><a href="#" alt="">{{$p->pro_name}}</a></label></div>

                      <h5 class="product-item-title">
                           {{$p->pro_code}}
                      </h5>

                      <!-- snippet location product_rating -->
                      <div class="product-item-price" data-product-price="JPY1,650">
                          <div>

                              <div class="product-price-line" data-product-price-wrapper="without-tax">
                                  {{--<span class="price-rrp highlight">RM-</span>--}}
                                  <meta itemprop="price" content="1650">
                                  <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="">
                                  <meta itemprop="availability" content="">
                                  <meta itemprop="itemCondition" itemtype="http://schema.org/OfferItemCondition" content="http://schema.org/Condition">
                                  <span class="price-value"> RM{{$p->pro_price}}</span>
                              </div>

                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </article>
          @endforeach
```

The result display shown as below: It should be coming out for display 1 message per click and not all of the message showing out.

[Image of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRo9U.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like below:

when you click on the button grab the id value and append it to your url

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', ".add-cart-cat", function() {

    var id = $(this).val(); //you can grab the value by any logic 

        $.ajax({
          url: '{{url("/cart/add")}}'+'/'+id,,
          method: 'GET',
          dataType: "json",
           context: this,
          success: function(data) {
            var successHtml = 'your success message div which will append to your desired div';
            // grab the id where you will append the div
            var target = $(this).attr('rel');
            $('#'+target).html(successHtml);

          }
        });

    }

});
```

in your controller addItem method return a success message string and append it in your desired div where you want to show it. but keep in mind that you should give a unique id to that div something like below:

```
 <div id='{{$p->id}}'>
 //you success message will append it through ajax
</div>
```

to grab this unique id you should do something like this in your `<a> anchor tag` put the `rel` attribute on it and give it a dynamic value just like below

```
<a href="#" rel='{{$p->id}}' class="button add-cart-cat button--small card-figcaption-button">Add to Cart</a>
```

**Note:** Don't mind about the structuring of my code but if you get the idea from this logic then you will definitely do it easily.

Comment: what i mention not the flash messages error, but come out the duplicate message when i click the button.

Comment: in that case you should not put the flash message in the loop, just put it outside the loop so it will be shown once.

Comment: Yes. I know but what I want is when click the add button on the image and show the message. means when click the 1st image of add button then display the message. click the 2nd image only will be display another message.

Comment: you should do this using ajax and in the ajax response only show the message to a specific image button which is clicked.

Comment: let me show an example in the answers section if you want to get the idea

Comment: Alright... I think i know what to code later. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From your $p in $data, can we get that item is in cart or not. If not, get that data in $p first and, then check before this code,

```
{{--Add Cart Message--}}
    @if($p->is_cart_added)
       @if (session('status'))
          <div class="alert alert-success">
          {{ session('status') }}
          </div>
       @endif
    @endif
```

Comment: I thought is using different ID, because pass the {{$p->id}} when I add to cart but i try to add @if($p->id), but result still same.

Comment: Message duplication is not because of the $p->id pass.  In your code you allow to show the message in all product, you have to add a condition (it should check the item is in cart or not) before message show.